# Stop an out-of-stock product returning to the product page when you add it to your cart

Tags: cart, addtocart

At the moment, if I add an item to my product which is out-of-stock, it goes to the product page with an "out of stock" message.

However, what I want is for it to still go to the cart page, but have an "out of stock" message there instead.

I am generating my link to add the product to the cart as follows: `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_newProduct);`

Comment: Do you want to sell the product actually even if it is out of stock?

Comment: No, it should not be added to the cart, but should just show the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `Mage_Checkout_CartController` and change the redirect behaviour of the `public function addAction()` to achieve what you are looking for.
I think you should check around line 260 of that class to see how the redirect is being performed.

`$this->_goBack();` is the function you are looking for.